# Check if string input equals string C#

Tags: c#

So I have this assignment and I'm having trouble making this part work.

My idea is that I want to list all of the Animal names and then ask the user to write down the name of the animal and then proceed to start playing with that animal.

My take is that I want to check if the name equals the name in the list that I have.

```
// It's in my Animal class where I hold the information on every animal.
List<Animal> animalList = new List<Animal>();
Console.WriteLine("Who do you want to play with?");
        List_Animal();

        string nameInput = Console.ReadLine();

        if (){

        } 

        else {
            Console.WriteLine("You wrote the wrong name. Try Again!");
        }
```

I'm not sure how I will be able to access the name variable.

```
class Animal {
      protected string name;

      public Animal(string name)
      {
           name = Name;
      }

      public string Name
      {
           get { return name; }
           set { name = value; }
      }
}
```

Any help?

Comment: I don't see no list of animals... To compare user input against a list of animal names, you would need to have such a list first, no?

Comment: Please show what you did that didn't work. If used correctly, both contains and any should work.

Comment: Well basically the animal list contains getters and setters that holds the information in wich this is the the list accessed:

List<Animal> animalList = new List<Animal>();

Comment: @ApolloBeached, `.Any()` will work.

Comment: I'm relatively new to programming so if you want more info just write and I'll do my best to answer

Comment: @ApolloBeached, well, you said that `.Any` hasn't worked. But you have not shown/explained how precisely you tried to use `.Any` and what the result or error was. Before anyone can give a meaningful answer you would need to explain more about the actual problem you encountered/observed. Please **EDIT** and improve your question with the missing information...

Comment: @elgonzo I edited it now and removed the part about any and contains because i feel like i've gotten it wrong in which i mean that I've written those methods the wrong way. I've basically tried to access the name variable without actually knowing how to do it other than looking at forums. Hopefully, this clears things up.

Comment: Ah, so you actually want to get the Animal object from the list that matches user input, and then continue using that particular Animal object, is that correct?

Comment: @elgonzo Correct :)

Comment: Okay, then `.Any` won't work, because it will only tell whether a maching Animal is in the list, but it will not retrieve/return the Animal object. Since your question is still closed (i voted to reopen it, but who knows when it will actually be reopened) i can't write up an answer. So i will answer in the next comment. Sadly, code formatting will suck :-( (1/2)

Comment: You can use Linq's [_FirstOrDefault_](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.firstordefault?view=netframework-4.7.1#System_Linq_Enumerable_FirstOrDefault__1_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Func___0_System_Boolean__) method like: `var animal = animalList.FirstOrDefault(a => a.Name == nameInput);` This method will either return the Animal object matching the predicate `a.Name == nameInput` or the default value `null` (`null` is the default value because Animal is a class). (2/3)

Comment: (3/3) So, to check whether the user input matched an animal, you could then do a simple check like `if (animal == null) { .... wrong input, no animal found ...}`. Otherwise - that is, if the _animal_ variable contains an Animal object - proceed to play with this Animal object ;-)

Comment: @elgonzo Wow, it worked! Thank you! :)

Answer (score 3):

Here is the main part of it.

```
string nameInput = Console.ReadLine();

List<string> animals = new List<string>(){"Bird", "Duck"};
animals.Add("Dog");
animals.Add("Cat");

if (animals.Contains(nameInput))
    Console.WriteLine("Exists");
else
    Console.WriteLine("Not Exists");
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the list of animals first and then check that list to see if any element matches `nameInput`.

```
List<Animal> animalList = new List<Animal>(); //Get the animal list here.
        if(animalList.Any(x=>x.name == nameInput))
        {

        }
        else {
         Console.WriteLine("You wrote the wrong name. Try Again!");
        }
```